# Tuple data keeps reverting after being changed from a list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am currently trying to change the value of Job in a tuple. I initially converted it to a list in order to do so, but after converting it back to a tuple and then calling a function to display the tuple, it still shows the original data.

```
x = [('Rae', 31, 'Student'),
     ('Anna', 30, 'Nurse')]

print(x)

def show_info():
    print(x)

def change_job(newJob, x):
    lst = list(x)
    name = x[0][0]
    age = x[0][1]
    job = newJob
    
    lst[0] = (name, age, job)
    print("List: ", lst[0])
    
    x = tuple(lst)
    print("Tuple: ", x[0])

newJob = input("What is your new job:")
change_job(newJob, x)
show_info()
```

```
[('Rae', 31, 'Student'), ('Anna', 30, 'Nurse')]
What is your new job:programmer
List:  ('Rae', 31, 'programmer')
Tuple:  ('Rae', 31, 'programmer')
[('Rae', 31, 'Student'), ('Anna', 30, 'Nurse')]
```

I coded it to show me what changes and it does change but if I run the show_info() it reverts it back to the old data.

Comment: `x` is a local variable, so assigning it has no effect on the global variable.

Comment: You're passing the list object into `change_job`, but when you say `x = tuple(lst)`, that just creates a new object and assigns it to your local variable `x`.  It doesn't change the global.  Perhaps you should RETURN that tuple, and do `x = change_job(newJob, x)`.  Or perhaps you should use meaningful variable names...

Comment: x is a list of tuples, so converting a list of tuples to a list, doesn't change the tuples inside the outer list

Answer (score 0):

Don't make a copy of `x`. Just assign a new tuple to the element of `x` that you want to replace.

```
def change_job(newJob, x):
    name = x[0][0]
    age = x[0][1]
    
    x[0] = (name, age, newJob)
    print("Tuple: ", x[0])
```